# Where are DC, positive frequencies, Nyquist and negative frequencies are located in DFT data for zero padded input

Tags: dft

It is still not so clear for me about DFT data and setting up data for IDFT wanted to ask few questions here.

complex input-data

1. Where are DC, +ve, Nyquist, -ve frequencies are located in DFT data for input where zeros are padded at the end and zeros are padded in the middle in time-domain.
2. How to setup DFT data for inverse transformation so that I get correct output?

real input-data

1. I presume the above two questions still hold but I am aware about the DFT of the real input data where the -ve frequencies are complex conjugate of +ve so only $N/2$ terms are computed.

Some time ago I got into a confusing discussion that DFT data is periodic so I need to move the data from $-N/2,...,0$ to $N/2,...,N-1$?
At that time I did not understand anything: Are they talking about the DFT of real input-data or complex input-data?

What else I miss?

Further, when using the libraries, such as fftw or intel how do they place those frequencies?

Comment: What has led you to the assumption that when you zero-pad a signal vector (be it complex or real) the DC, positive, negative and Nyquist frequencies will be at different places? I mean, practically they will be but their relative positions will remain the same. Negative will remain before DC, positive above DC and Nyquist at the end of the positive frequencies (when $N$ is even). Regarding the programming libraries, the position of negative frequencies is implementation dependent just because, like you’ve been said, DFT is periodic and negative and “past Nyquist” frequencies have the same info

Comment: after asking this question I thought about it then I understood like what you have answered. The transformation does not care about input whether its is dense or sparse. Its nature is to give DC, +ve, Nyquist, -ve?

Comment: Yeah, in a sense. But keep in mind that it may be -ve, DC, +ve, Nyquist. This depends on the implementation, but if you are targeting for something specific (for your own reasons) you can convert from one to the other just be circularly shifting half the vector to bring -ve to the left of DC or the right of Nyquist…… Could you please either answer your own question and accept it I could write a short answer and if you feel it is adequate accept it? This way, reference in the future will be possible for people with similar problems/questions.

Comment: you can write a short answer please.